# Recursive CTE to traverse a hierarchy with dual descendant IDs

Tags: mysql, recursion

Given the following table of sports matches with two players:

| match_id | match_date | p1_id | p2_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 02/01/2022 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 03/01/2022 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 04/01/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 05/01/2022 | 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 06/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 07/01/2022 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 08/01/2022 | 3 | 4 |
| 9 | 09/01/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 10/01/2022 | 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 11/01/2022 | 3 | 4 |
| 12 | 12/01/2022 | 7 | 8 |
| 13 | 13/01/2022 | 3 | 1 |
| 14 | 14/01/2022 | 5 | 7 |
| 15 | 15/01/2022 | 4 | 5 |

I’m trying to write a query with a recursive CTE that when given a `match_id` the query will return all `match_id` values for future matches for each of the two players. The recursion is needed because I need the query to also include all future matches for any of the future matches' players.

Using the example above and `match_id = 6` then the two player IDs are `1` and `2`. I need the query to return all future matches for these player IDs. This means the query needs to return `7`, `9` and `13`. However, in `match_id = 7` player ID `1` plays player ID `3` so now all of their future `match_id` values from that point also need to be included. This means the query also needs to return `8` and `11`. In `match_id = 8` and `match_id = 11` player ID `3` plays player ID `4` so the final `match_id` to be returned is `15`.

The expected output is as follows:

| match_id |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 11 |
| 13 |
| 15 |

I've written the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE match_ids AS (
    SELECT
        m1.match_id,
        m1.match_date,
        m1.p1_id,
        m1.p2_id
    FROM recursive_test AS m1
    WHERE m1.match_id = 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        m2.match_id,
        m2.match_date,
        m2.p1_id,
        m2.p2_id
    FROM recursive_test AS m2
    INNER JOIN match_ids
        ON (
            match_ids.p1_id = m2.p1_id
            OR match_ids.p1_id = m2.p2_id
            OR match_ids.p2_id = m2.p1_id
            OR match_ids.p2_id = m2.p2_id
        )
            AND match_ids.match_date > m2.match_date
)
SELECT match_id
FROM match_ids
```

However, this returns:

| match_id |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

Where might I be going wrong?

Here's the SQL to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `recursive_test` (
  `match_id` int NOT NULL,
  `match_date` date NOT NULL,
  `p1_id` int NOT NULL,
  `p2_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `recursive_test` VALUES (1,'2022-01-01',1,2),(2,'2022-01-02',3,1),(3,'2022-01-03',3,4),(4,'2022-01-04',2,3),(5,'2022-01-05',5,6),(6,'2022-01-06',1,2),(7,'2022-01-07',3,1),(8,'2022-01-08',3,4),(9,'2022-01-09',2,3),(10,'2022-01-10',5,6),(11,'2022-01-11',3,4),(12,'2022-01-12',7,8),(13,'2022-01-13',3,1),(14,'2022-01-14',5,7),(15,'2022-01-15',4,5);
```

Comment: *Here's the SQL to create the table* - the SQL code data differs from shown table data. *this returns nothing* - maybe because of the above issue?

Comment: Hey. Really sorry - I'd updated the primary keys in Workbench and then not hit `Apply`. Will update the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM recursive_test
    WHERE match_id = @starting_match_id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT recursive_test.*
    FROM recursive_test
    JOIN cte ON recursive_test.match_date > cte.match_date
    WHERE recursive_test.p1_id IN (cte.p1_id, cte.p2_id)
       OR recursive_test.p2_id IN (cte.p1_id, cte.p2_id)
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM cte;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ca1e57845bae995bacb04455beb6340

Comment: I've updated the dbfiddle to reflect the correct data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2453e8ccac4eb7ba8779208f4e53f0ea. This works perfectly thank you! I just need to figure out why :)